# Difference in Tikhonov regularization for linear and non-linear case?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, least-squares, adjoint-operators, regularization, inverse-problems

the Tikhonov regularization for a linear operator $T: X \rightarrow Y, x \mapsto y$ means minimizing the least square problem

$$\begin{align*} 
\lVert Tx - y \rVert^2_Y + \alpha \lVert x\rVert_X \rightarrow \min_{x\in X}
\end{align*}$$

This is equivalent to solving the regularized normal equations

$$\begin{align}
(T^*T+\alpha I)x = T^*y,
\end{align}$$

where $T^*$ is the adjoint operator of $T$.

Now I've currently read about the nonlinear case. Apparently, minimizing the above mentioned Tikhonov functional leads to the equation

$$\begin{align}
T'(x)^* (T(x)-y) + \alpha x = 0 \quad
\Rightarrow  \quad T'(x)^*T(x)+\alpha x = T'(x)^*y
\end{align}$$

I compared both expressions and I am wondering why the derivative of $T$ appears in the non-linear case but not in the linear one.

If I plug in a linear operator into the nonlinear expression, I feel like it should be equal to the linear regularized normal equations. But there is definitely a difference between a linear operator and its derivative, which would be a constant operator.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confused by the notation. Lets say we have some transformation $f$ acting on $x$, i.e. $f(x)$.

The Problem can be stated as:

$$
\min_x \,\{\lVert f(x)-y\rVert^2 + \lambda\lVert x\rVert^2\}
$$

Taking the gradient w.r.t. $x$ yields:
$$
\frac{d\Phi}{dx} = f'(x)(f(x)-y)+\lambda x
$$

If $f(x)$ is a linear transformation, then
$$
f(x) = Tx
$$
and hence
$$
f'(x) = T^*
$$
Which in turn would again mean:
$$
(T^*T+\lambda I)x = T^*y
$$

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. Unfortunately, I feel like I am still missing a lot.  How is the derivative of f (w.r.t. to x? ) equivalent to $T^*$? And does that mean that $f'(x)$ does not see an argument ( x) and is constant?

Comment: In the linear case, the $f'(x)$ is constant and equal to $T^*$. In the nonlinear case, $f'(x)$ would be called the Jacobian and would be a function of $x$.